# Sending a JSON data through HTTP Get using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

We have a web service(GET) that takes a complex JSON with lists, 
How do I set it up so that requests sends the generated data as json and not through query string?

Here's the simplified version of the current code and I keep on getting error 403:

```
def build_get_request_params(table_name):
    data = {'table_data': table_name}
    return data

def get_table_data_prefixed(table_name):
    built = build_get_request_params(table_name)
    response = requests.get("https://www.endpoint", data=json.dump(built))
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: `GET` requests can only send parameters through the query string.

Comment: Are you sure the web service wants the parameters in JSON format? If it uses `GET`, it almost certainly wants them in URL-encoded format.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding it as `params` instead:

```
def build_get_request_params(table_name):
    data = {'table_name': table_name,
            'prefixed': True
            }
    return data


def get_table_data_prefixed(table_name):
    built = build_get_request_params(table_name)
    response = requests.get("http://www.endpoint.com", params=built)
    print(response.json())
```